# CSS3 Animations on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, animate.css

So presently I was developing a webapp to be used via mobile devices.

I am using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for animations.

While the animations work fine on a desktop browser, the are very laggy and uneven on a mobile browser.

Since animate.css is using plain CSS3 animations, I don't understand why animations are not working.

So,

1. Why are mobile browsers so bad in rendering CSS3 Animations ?
2. Is there any faster way to render animations on a mobile browser ?
   (for eg. using javascript maybe)

Comment: What mobile browser/device are you using?

Comment: I've never had any problems with this subject, having used both BlackBerry™ and Android.

Comment: it depends on which features do you require, but generic overview you may get from this link: http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3 . I'd say there will be no problems, you have to use CSS3.